# Switch to another screen when notification is clicked work in debug not in prod

Tags: flutter

This my main code

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if(message.notification != null) {
    handleScreen(message);
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
 
  // Gestion firebase_messaging
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  Utilities().manageFirebaseTopic();

  await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleScreen(message);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
    if(message != null) {
        handleScreen(message);
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if(message.notification != null) {
      handleScreen(message);
    }
  });

  runApp(const MyAppScreen());
}

String id = message.data["id"];
  String level = message.data["level"];
  String screen = message.data["screen"];
  String subject = message.data["subject"];
  String courseType = message.data["course_type"];

  if(screen == "premium"){
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const NavScreen()
                      )
                  );
                  return false;
                },
                child: const PremiumScreen()
            )
        )
    );
  }
  else if(screen == "aide"){
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const NavScreen()
                      )
                  );
                  return false;
                },
                child: const HelpScreen()
            )
        )
    );
  }

class MyAppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppScreenState();
}

class MyAppScreenState extends State<MyAppScreen> {
  FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

  Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) async{
      LocalData().setReferralCode(dynamicLinkData.link.path.replaceAll("/", ""));
    }).onError((_) {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks();
    Utilities().tracking("StartScreen", "StartScreen");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'TAKTIK',
        theme: ThemeData(
            splashColor: Colors.white,
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.white
          )
        ),
        home: const StartScreen(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
        supportedLocales: const [
          Locale('en', ''),
          Locale('fr', '')
        ],
        navigatorKey : navigatorKey
    );
  }
}
```

this my startscreen code

```
class StartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StartScreen> createState() => StartScreenState();
}

class StartScreenState extends State<StartScreen> {

  void isConnected(){
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)async{
      String appRemoteVersion = await Utilities().remoteConfigValue("appVersion");
      if(Constants.appLocalVersion != appRemoteVersion){
        if(!mounted) return;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const AppNewVersionScreen()
            )
        );
      }
      else{
        if(LocalData().isConnected()){
          if(!mounted) return;
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NavScreen())
          );
        }
        else{
          if(!mounted) return;
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()
              )
          );
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    isConnected();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 0,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xff0b65c2))
              )
            ]
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Th startscreen code is use to verify if user is connected to switch to appropiate screen.

In my main code, I use FCM to jump to the screen if the user clicks on the notification. It works perfectly, but when the application is closed and the user clicks on a notification, the screen should appear for a certain second and disappears.

The problem is in the startscreen code, I made a notification.pushreplacement which creates this problem, but I don't know how to avoid it

Comment: any error(s)???

Comment: I dont see error, it's work in debug perfectly without error, and when i send my app in prod it's not work

Comment: you can use `flutter run --release` to test on release mode.

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: flutter run --release dont work is return many errors

Comment: Error appear when notification clicked? What is the error?

Comment: I update question to explain more.

Comment: What problem? Please paste the exception.

Comment: There is no problem just that the first screen is displayed and the second comes to close, how to avoid that.